# PNP Dynamic Form - cascading look up column and tabs

Tags: sharepoint-online, pnp, spfx-extensions

Can you please help me on below topics regarding to PNP Dynamic form in SPFx

how to filter and cascade look up column
how to arrange fileds in tabs

Thanks
Praveen

Comment: Please add details about what you've tried and what isn't working. Currently there isn't enough information to help you.